# p:ajax inside h:commandButton not call backing bean method

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to call my backing bean method using `<p:ajax>` but it doesn't work. My `<p:ajax>` is wrapped inside an `<h:commandButton>` like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msg['supprimer.image']}"
    styleClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger" update=":uploader"
     process="@this">

    <p:ajax event="click" update="imagesList" process="@this"
    listener="#{creationBesoinBean.supprimerImage(uploadedImage)}"/> 
</h:commandButton>
```

But supprimerImage method is not invocked. Could somehone help me please?

Comment: You have initially tagged [`[primefaces]`](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30411310/1). Besides, `<p:ajax>` implicitly refers to PrimeFaces. As such, why don't you use a `<p:commandButton>` with `action(Listener)`, `process` and `update` instead which is Ajaxical by nature?

Answer (score 3):

The method listener should have this signature in backing bean

```
public void supprimerImage ()

<p:ajax event="click" update="imagesList" process="@this"
            listener="#{creationBesoinBean.supprimerImage}"></p:ajax>
```

Comment: i'd like pass a parameter to my backingBean method that's why i used <p:ajax event="click" update="imagesList" process="@this"
    listener="#{creationBesoinBean.supprimerImage(uploadedImage)}"/> and the signature of my method is supprimerImage(BesoinFile file).

Comment: try to define variable (BesoinFile file) inside bean and create getter/setter then use it inside the method and page without changing signature of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Click event name for `p:ajax` is `onclick` not `click`.
Search for "Ajax Behavior Events" in [PrimeFaces User's Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html) of your Primefaces Version, you get more info on `p:ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces p:ajax already uses the default event for the elements it is attached to, in the case of a commandButton the click method.

The following code invokes just fine:

```
<h:commandButton value="Do Stuff" styleClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
    update=":uploader" process="@this">
<p:ajax process="@this"
    listener="#{creationBesoinBean.supprimerImage}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="referenceUploadedImageHere"
        target="#{creationBesoinBean.image}" />
    </p:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

The Listener-Method of p:ajax has to look as follows:

```
public void supprimerImage(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
```

If you use the action-Tag of a button, they need to look like this:

```
public void supprimerImage()
```

ActionListener-Methods for example in p:buttons like this:

```
public void supprimerImage(ActionEvent event)
```

As for how to use the Uploaded Image, either keep it stored in the bean and use it inside the Listener-Method of p:ajax, or set it with f:setPropertyListener. Also I would concur with Tiny's recommendation and use a p:commandButton, which has actionListener and action built-in, so you don't clutter your code with p:ajax Tags.